# Did High Sierra break custom sounds for NSUserNotifications?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-high-sierra

In the past it was possible to play a custom sound with user notifications by placing the sound file into one of the library folders. Starting with High Sierra this seems to be broken.

For a sound file stored in `~/Library/Sounds` the following still works, even for sandboxed apps:

```
[[NSSound soundNamed:@"my sound"] play];
```

However, using the same sound name in an `NSUserNotification` does not work any more. In this case, the standard system notification sound gets played.

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
notification.title = @"Title goes here";
notification.soundName = @"my sound";
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]
    deliverNotification:notification]
```

This definitely worked in Sierra (and previous versions). Is this a know bug or is it even documented somewhere? Apple's documentation is pretty useless regarding this topic.

Comment: The header comments only mention the app bundle (at least on 10.13); maybe they “fixed” it?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I hadn't looked at the header. It really seems like the behaviour in High Sierra might be intentional.